# Auth error when sending mail through Postfix with SSMTP

Tags: postfix, sendmail, mailx, ssmtp

I'm trying to send mail from server A running SSMTP via a server B running Postfix. The Postfix server is running just fine and has been in production for a while without any problems. It runs Postfix with Dovecot.

I can use my Gmail account to send mail from SSMTP and that works however I want to use my own Postfix server because I want more control over the entire mail process.

**In the next logs and code I have replaced my own public domain with example.com.**

Here is the error that SSMTP produces:

```
root@N40L:/etc/ssmtp# echo "test" | mailx -vvv -s "test" martin@example.com
[<-] 220 h******.stratoserver.net ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
[->] EHLO example.com
[<-] 250 DSN
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
send-mail: Server didn't like our AUTH LOGIN (535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism)
```

I'm running Debian 8 on both machines.

Here is my ssmtp.conf:

```
root=N40L@example.com
mailhub=example.com:465
rewriteDomain=example.com
hostname=example.com
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=N40L@example.com
AuthPass=correctpassword
```

I know SSMTP sometimes has trouble working with non-alphanumeric passwords so the password is a string of letters and numbers. I have verified it using Mutt and I'm certain it is the right password, the right username, the right port.

Postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ********.stratoserver.net
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.stratoserver.net, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
message_size_limit=20480000
virtual_mailbox_domains = a.bunch.of names.here.and example.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = scan:127.0.0.1:10026
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
```

The LetsEncrypt certs show the correct name and a host of phones, both Android and iPhone, as well as a number of different mail clients and its webmail are all satisfied with it. I am positive the certs are in order.

master.cf, though I'm not sure it is relevant:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v
 -o content_filter=spamassassin
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
scan      unix  -       -       n       -       16      smtp
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes

127.0.0.1:10025 inet  n -       n       -       16      smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o mynetworks_style=host
        -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

Relevant config parts in Dovecot:

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_verbose = yes
mail_debug = yes
mail_plugins = " quota"
mail_privileged_group = vmail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt//live/example.com/privkey.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
verbose_ssl = yes
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " quota sieve"
  postmaster_address = me@example.com
}
```

If I try to send mail from server A and it generates aforementioned error server B log this in /var/mail/mail.log:

```
Jan 16 10:29:54 postfix/smtps/smtpd[13601]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Jan 16 10:29:54 postfix/smtps/smtpd[13601]: connect from ******.upc-h.chello.nl[62.194.***.***]
Jan 16 10:29:54 dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=0)
Jan 16 10:29:54 postfix/smtps/smtpd[13601]: warning: ******.upc-h.chello.nl[62.194.***.***]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
Jan 16 10:29:54 postfix/smtps/smtpd[13601]: lost connection after AUTH from ******.upc-h.chello.nl[62.194.***.***]
Jan 16 10:29:54 postfix/smtps/smtpd[13601]: disconnect from ******.upc-h.chello.nl[62.194.***.***]
```

Same if I add `AuthMechanism=LOGIN` or `AuthMechanism=CRAM-MD5` (which according to SSMTP's man page are the only mechanisms available) to ssmtp.conf so I removed that again.

Because the internet is very insistant on using Gmail with SSMTP I tried to humor it for a bit and tried UseSTARTTLS. This then happens on server A:

```
send-mail: Cannot open example.com:465
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

...and this is logged on server B:

```
Jan 16 10:46:01 postfix/smtps/smtpd[14047]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Jan 16 10:46:01 postfix/smtps/smtpd[14047]: connect from ******.upc-h.chello.nl[62.194.***.***]
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: elliptic curve secp384r1 will be used for ECDH and ECDHE key exchanges
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: elliptic curve secp384r1 will be used for ECDH and ECDHE key exchanges
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=14049)
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0111#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=***************AAAAAAAAAAB#011lip=::1#011rip=::1#011lport=143#011rport=60112#011resp=AG40MGxAd*****************QzE3MDE= (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth-worker(14017): Debug: sql(n40l@example.com,::1): query: SELECT email as username, pwd AS password FROM addresses WHERE email = 'n40l@example.com'
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK#0111#011user=n40l@example.com
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST#011154140673#01114049#0111#0114d206d2a85468af9af75b8538aab7485#011session_pid=14050#011request_auth_token
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth-worker(14017): Debug: sql(n40l@example.com,::1): SELECT 5000 AS uid, 5000 as gid, email, '/var/mail/vmail/example.com/n40l' AS home FROM addresses WHERE email = 'n40l@example.com'
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER#011154140673#011n40l@example.com#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011email=n40l@example.com#011home=/var/mail/vmail/example.com/n40l#011auth_token=ff5b12*****************aedf315ac08e
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n40l@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=14050, secured, session=<0pDTDTNG0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib10_quota_plugin.so
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/email=n40l@example.com
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: Effective uid=5000, gid=5000, home=/var/mail/vmail/example.com/n40l
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: Quota root: name=User quota backend=maildir args=
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=* bytes=10737418240 messages=0
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=Trash bytes=+104857600 messages=0
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: Quota grace: root=User quota bytes=536870912 (5%)
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/var/mail/vmail/example.com/n40l
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/mail/vmail/example.com/n40l, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/mail/vmail/example.com/n40l, alt=
Jan 16 10:46:12 dovecot: imap(n40l@example.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=50 out=475
```

I can log into server B's webmail without any trouble and send and receive mail for the address I'm using so the account itself is in order. I tried other accounts and they produce the same errors.

I'm at a loss. SSMTP should be able to send mail through Postfix. Even with all debug and verbosity options on, I can't find the source of the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
root@N40L:/etc/ssmtp# echo "test" | mailx -vvv -s "test" martin@example.com
[<-] 220 h******.stratoserver.net ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
[->] EHLO example.com
[<-] 250 DSN
```

The command connected to Postfix at `h******.stratoserver.net` and sent its `EHLO` introduction. But the received response with just `250 DSN` indicates this Postfix is not willing to accept authentication at this point. If it would accept authentication, the response might look more like this:

```
[<-] 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
[<-] 250 DSN
```

Essentially, the server's answer to the client's `EHLO` will inform the client about the SMTP protocol features this particular server is willing to accept. For authentication, there should be a line with the word `AUTH` and a list of acceptable authentication mechanisms. A multi-line response will have a result code of the client's previous command and a minus sign (`250-` here) at the beginning of each line except the last one: the last line of the answer will have the result code and a space character instead.

Your `ssmtp.conf` indicates it would be using port 465, which corresponds to service name `smtps`:

```
mailhub=example.com:465
```

So the relevant Postfix `master.cf` entry will be this one:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

This looks incomplete to me.

To allow sending mail through this port only when authenticated, you would need `-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject` here also, just like with the previous `submission` service (`submission` is the service operating in port 587). You will also need `-o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous`.

To use specifically Dovecot SASL with Postfix, you would need a `-o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot` line in there. You might also need `-o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth`: when using Dovecot SASL with Postfix, this will identify the location of the Dovecot SASL authentication socket, which is specified in Dovecot configuration as

```
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
```

But since the `smtpd` process of Postfix will use `/var/spool/postfix` as its working directory (and may in fact be chrooted there), `smtpd` only needs the `private/auth` part of this path.

In order to use STARTTLS, you would have to use port 587 instead, and as a diagnostic, the EHLO response of Postfix on that port would have to include `250-STARTTLS`.

The typical sequence of events with STARTTLS is:

1. the client makes an unencrypted connection to port 587 and sends an `EHLO`
2. the server response includes `STARTTLS` but no `AUTH`, at least not with `PLAIN` or `LOGIN` mechanisms, as sending authentication data without encryption is not very smart.
3. the client sends a `STARTTLS` command, and both parties begin a TLS handshaking immediately.
4. when TLS is in effect, the client will send another `EHLO`
5. now the server's response will include `AUTH` with all the authentication mechanisms allowed by the server administrator.

I know this is a very late answer for the OP, but perhaps this will help someone else figure out how the various pieces of configuration fit together. (It certainly was a refresh of Postfix authentication knowledge for me.)

Answer (score 0):

ssmtp seems to simulate an Outlook client, because it uses broken auth mechanism.

`broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes` in postfix main.cf will "fix" this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't help and nothing's changed.